# MAUI: UI and App-Breaking Issues on Android Version 8

Tags: maui

I am facing UI and App-Breaking issues in my MAUI project only on Android Version 8. There are no issues on Android Versions 10, 11, and 12.

UI Issue:
In the below screenshot, we are showing the text using the label inside of a frame. "Select a Category" label alignment is incorrect, and the label "Choose the file" touches the frame.

[image]

Actual UI:

[image]

App-Breaking Issues:

I am getting an exception, and the app breaks when loading a few Popups and Content pages.

I am getting the exception below when loading the Popup page:

```
 Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no non-static method "Landroid/view/WindowInsets;.getSystemGestureInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets;"'
```

I am getting the exception below when loading the Content page:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to draw too large(131320128bytes) bitmap.'
```

I have tried different solutions to fix these issues, but didn't help. Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve these issues on Android Version 8?

**Update**

I have created a demo project with the issues and upload [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zJj0Pytlor8YMwB3Mh-RfDpEuWGjHOIv/view?usp=sharing)

In this demo project, we have two options. We tap on the first option, which is a Popup page, and tap on the second option, which is a content page. This project works fine on Android Version 10, 11, and 12. But in Android version 8, when we tap on both options, the app breaks and gets exceptions.

I am getting the exception below when loading the Popup page:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no non-static method
> "Landroid/view/WindowInsets;.getSystemGestureInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets;"'

I am getting the exception below when loading the Content page:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to draw too large(131320128bytes) bitmap.'

Comment: Can you provide some codes to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT We have added a demo project with this issues, could you please check.

Comment: I tested the project you provided. It has the issue when I click the item to start the popup Page on Android 8, and I notice that you are using the NuGet package `Rg.Plugins.Popup` to realize the popup. This package does not provide the Android minimum support version. It might be the package's issue, so you can create an issue request on the GitHub to ask the developer if it support the Android 8.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Any comments for the second issue? When opening a content page also we are facing an exception.

Comment: It might be the images you used in the project are too large. You can check the answer about [Android: Canvas: trying to draw too large](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59099261/19335715). Besides, I found the `Rg.Plugins.Popup` package's [MonoAndroid version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup#supportedframeworks-body-tab) is Android 10.

Comment: We are using a RGPopup.Maui package https://www.nuget.org/packages/RGPopup.Maui#dependencies-body-tab and not a Rg.Plugins.Popup package. Does RGPopup.Maui package support in Android version 8?

Comment: It is a third-party package. It is better for you to ask the developer on the GitHub issue. I found the [same error report](https://github.com/microspaze/RGPopup.Maui/issues/2) in the issue thread of the RGPopup.Maui package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post as a Summary:

For the error,

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no non-static method
> "Landroid/view/WindowInsets;.getSystemGestureInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets;"'

This caused by the `Rg.Plugins.Popup` NuGet Package. The MonoAndroid version of the package is Android 10. So it cannot be built on the Android 9.

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to draw too
> large(131320128bytes) bitmap.'

It might be the images you used in the project are too large. You can check the answer about [Android: Canvas: trying to draw too large](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59099261/19335715).

For the UI issue, you can try to replace the frame to the border. Frame is for people migrating apps from Xamarin.Forms.